# passing direct3d shader parameters dynamically

Tags: c++, parameters, shader, direct3d9

I want to make my brightness and contrast shader change by dynamically changing offset parameters, but I dont want to recompile my shader everytime I am changing shader buffer.

The current shader code is

```
char shaderCode[] = " \
sampler2D screen: register(s0); \
\
float offsetBrightness = 0.0f; \
float offsetContrast   = 0.9f; \
float4 PSBrightnessContrast(float2 inCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0\
{\
    return (tex2D(screen, inCoord.xy) + offsetBrightness) * (1.0 + offsetContrast);\
}\
\
technique brightness \
{ \
    pass p1 \
    { \
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PSBrightnessContrast(); \
    } \
} \
";
```

How I can pass the `offsetBrightness` and `offsetContrast` dynamically?

Comment: You need uniforms. I don't know DirectX, so I can't tell you how to use them exactly, read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HLSL, all variables declared outside function can be changed between each draw call.

To change their value you can use the following setter from ID3DXEffect :

`HRESULT SetFloat(
  [in]  D3DXHANDLE hParameter,
  [in]  FLOAT f
);`

where hParameter can be either the name as char * or the handle queried using `GetParameterHandle()`

So in your example :

effet->SetFloat( "offsetBrightness", 0.5f );

If you are inside a `Begin()/End()`, you need to call `CommitChanges()`to apply those values